# Animating widgets positions while scrolling

Tags: android, animation, dart, flutter

I'm trying to animate widgets in my app depending of the user's scroll and the position inside my scrolling widget (`CustomScrollView`).

So far i achieved something that looks very nice using the method i'll show below, but i'm afraid that this specific method:

1. Is not the most effective in terms of performance and resources.
2. Is not the smoothest and result in non-fluid animations.
3. Won't be consistent across all sort of devices and resolutions.

Here is what i want to achieve, notice the text's position, and the scrolling page indicator at the bottom-left corner:

[image: The animations]

I achieved it by doing the following steps:

1. Creating a function (`_offsetPosition`) which gets the current offset, an index of the page which the widget belongs to, the device's view-port dimensions and a coefficient i'm using to speed or slow the animation. The function will return a value between -1.0 and 1.0, while -1.0 is before the page shows up until the very moment it shows on the screen, 1.0 just when it disappears, and 0.0 is exactly when the page fills my view-port.
2. Use that function inside a listener for the `ScrollController` and changing the value of a variable according to the scroll and other constants i define to make it change according to my needs.
3. Using that variable as `Padding` for my widget (or for any other parameter, `Opacity` for example).

Here is the `_offsetPosition` function:

```
double _offsetPosition(double currentOffset, int pageIndex,
    double viewportDimension, double coefficient) {
  // Returns a value between -1.0 (left edge and before) to 1.0 (right edge and after).
  // 1.0 when the page fills the viewport exactly.
  // Making sure the return value won't be below -1.0 or 1.0 to avoid errors.
  double position = (currentOffset - pageIndex * viewportDimension) *
      coefficient /
      viewportDimension;

  if (position <= -1.0) {
    return -1.0;
  } else if (position >= 1.0) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return position;
  }
}
```

This is the listener i define inside my `initState` to change the variables values and `build` the screen when it changes:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      _pagePosition = _scrollController.offset /
          _scrollController.position.viewportDimension;

      _bg1Parallax = 0.2 -
          _offsetPosition(_scrollController.offset, 0,
                  _scrollController.position.viewportDimension, 1.0) *
              0.4;

      _bg2Parallax = 0.2 -
          _offsetPosition(_scrollController.offset, 1,
                  _scrollController.position.viewportDimension, 1.0) *
              0.4;

      _text1Padding = _offsetPosition(_scrollController.offset, 0,
              _scrollController.position.viewportDimension, 1.0) *
          1000.0;

      _text1Opacity = max(
          0.0,
          1.0 -
              _offsetPosition(_scrollController.offset, 0,
                      _scrollController.position.viewportDimension, 3.0)
                  .abs());
    });
  });
}
```

And here is an example for the text and icon widgets that moves when the user scrolls, since the value of `_pagePosition` and `_text1Padding` grows when the user scrolls forward and vice versa:

**Icon widget:**

```
new Padding(
  padding:
      new EdgeInsets.only(left: _pagePosition * 20.0),
  child: new Padding(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: new Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.circle,
      size: 15.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Text widget:**

```
new Padding(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _text1Padding),
  child: new Center(
    child: new Opacity(
      opacity: _text1Opacity,
      child: new Text(
        'Text',
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 100.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

### **TL;DR**

Should i animate a widget's position using a value that changes, according to the `ScrollController` offset, as a `Padding` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run your app in release mode, on a real device?

In general it should not be a problem to rebuild the widget tree when the scroll position changes because Flutter was built to handle this efficiently (the underlying heavy `RenderObject` tree is not rebuilt).

An alternative approach would be the usage of custom `RenderSliver`s, [as demonstrated in the flutter_gallery example application](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/animation/home.dart). You can download the application on Google Play (in the App, select Studies > Animation).

I recorded a video of the animations:
https://i.imgur.com/Pj9x09q.mp4

[image]
<sub>(source: [flutter.io](https://flutter.io/images/homepage/screenshot-1.png))</sub>